# CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK when value has not changed

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

Imagine I have a table with change tracking enabled, and I update a column of the table for a given primary key. The value I update with is the SAME value as was already there before.

Looking on the [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895238(v=sql.110).aspx), MSDN says that this function will return true if the column is in the collection change_columns.

> CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK returns the following values.
>
> 0: The specified column is not in the change_columns list.
>
> 1: The specified column is in the change_columns list.

Looking [further](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934145(v=sql.110).aspx), the *change_columns* list is a wrapper around the CHANGETABLE.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS property, which is defined as:

> Lists the columns that have changed since the last_sync_version (the
>   baseline).

Which is ambiguous. What does "changed" mean in this context? If the value is the same then has it changed?

Anyone know the answer?

Comment: I suspect that in order to keep the tracking mechanism light weight, it does not compare the value before and after but rather uses a mechanism similar to (if not exactly) the columns_updated function.

Comment: @BenThul - yes that would have been my suspicion too. In fact, I tried it and we were both correct. Go instincts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it and can report that yes, CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK returns true when a column value has been changed, regardless of what the actual change delta was.

Comment: Even if it wasn't so, consider that change tracking only reports that changes have occurred, not how many changes nor the intermediate values. So if all your `A` values start off as `1`, the updates `UPDATE Tbl SET A = 2` followed by `UPDATE Tbl SET A = 1` would be indistinguishable from your non-update in the question so you'd need to handle that situation anyway.